# What does java "VM thread" do?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I use jstack to output the thread info. And there is a thread:
"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0878b400 nid=0x760a runnable

What is this thread used to do?
It takes 50% CPU usage and most of CPU time

Comment: Which virtual machine implementation in what environment?

Answer (score 11):

The VM thread is defined [here](http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html) as:

> This thread waits for operations to appear that require the JVM to reach a safe-point. The reason these operations have to happen on a separate thread is because they all require the JVM to be at a safe point where modifications to the heap can not occur. The type of operations performed by this thread are "stop-the-world" garbage collections, thread stack dumps, thread suspension and biased locking revocation.

There's also some information provided in a de-duplicated SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432587/what-is-the-role-of-vm-thread-in-jdk-1-6?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Answer (score 2):

The **VM thread** is an internal JVM thread and you would not see that in JConsole but on an `threaddump` (use `jstack`) or OS utility such as `top (top -H .... )` or `ps`.

This VM Thread if it is consistently taking a huge amount of CPU could be a **precursor to an OOM** Heap error.

This usually can happen when there are "stop the world" GC happening. It could be due to a memory leak or as innocuous as running on a single CPU and / or a Serial GC Collector and / or loading the heap with objects that cannot be GC'ed since they are active on the stack and / or sizing the heap too low compared to workflow and implied concurrency etc..

Example below.

It is simple to replicate:

try running on a constrained heap (say 256m), limit to a single cpu (using docker or an OS specific utility), specify a larger number of worker threads that read images into memory and you would see that with this command (on linux):

```
top -n 1 -H -p {pid}
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                      
   10 root      20   0 3335964 395380  28380 R  60.0  19.4   0:34.71 VM Thread
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the Garbage Collection thread. It does Garbage Collection.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that this thread is taking 50% usage? Being runnable doesn't mean its consuming cpu.

AFAIK this is used for internal java operation, possibly involved in GC.

Which version of java are you using? I would check you have an up to date version of Java and see if this still happens.

I would suggest you memory profile your application to see how much objects you are creating and see if you can reduce your object count to reduce any GC work load.