# what is the role of "vm thread" in JDK 1.6

Tags: java, garbage-collection, solaris, java-6

We are seeing lot of activity of this thread in our customer's system and hence would like to know what might be happening.

any links, info, tutorials ?

P.S : this is happening on Solaris 10 with JDK 1.6.0_23.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this thread will give you some step to proceed. If possible i will provide more.
http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-dev/2009-February/001249.html

This some more details i can share about VM thread

If the “Current thread” is the VMThread then you need to look for the “VM_Operation” line in the
THREAD section. The VM thread is a special thread in the HotSpot VM. It performs special tasks in
the VM such as garbage collection. If the VM_Operation suggests that the operation is a garbage
collection then it is possible that you have encountered as issue such as heap corruption. The crash
might also be a garbage collector issue, but it could equally be something else (such as a compiler or
runtime bug) that leaves object references in the heap in an inconsistent or incorrect state. In this case
it is best to collect as much information as possible about the environment and try out possible
workarounds. If the issue is GC related then you may be able to temporarily workaround the issue by
changing the GC configuration. This is discussed in the following section.

also check this link for more information http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jdk50-ts-guide-149808.pdf